# React Native navigation reset stack

Tags: react-native, navigation, state, react-navigation

I have a tabBar in my application that consist of 2 stacks, `home` and `profile`.

When the user clicks on one of them, I want to clear my stack and navigate to the other stack. Up until now, I used `popToTop()` like this:

```
         if (state.index > 0) {
          navigation.popToTop() 
         }
         navigation.navigate(route.name)
```

When my stack has more than one screen in it, it works as expected.
The problem is when the stack is empty, I get a warning: (although I check that the state index is greater than 0)

> The action 'POP_TO_TOP' was not handled by any navigator.

I tried solving it by using `navigation.reset()` like this:

```
navigation.reset({index: 0, routes: [{ name: route.name }]})
```

It seems to work, but I was wondering if this is good practice, or is there better way to solve this?

Comment: did you try navigation.canGoBack() instead of the state.index? Without trying I thought this was the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I did, the same warning occurs... @Christian